# Cannot run iOS React Native app in Release Schema

Tags: ios, react-native, production

When I switch my iOS project to the release schema (as described https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device.html), I get this error:

> 2016-11-29 11:49:01.621 [fatal][tid:main] No script URL provided. Make sure the packager is running or you have embedded a JS bundle in your application bundle.unsanitizedScriptURLString:((null))

Do I need to create a static js bundle in production mode? The docs suggest that in earlier React Native docs, but I'm running React Native 0.35 (originally 0.30)

Comment: How did you upgrade your app from 0.30 to 0.35? Did you run `react-native upgrade` afterwards? Your `AppDelegate.m` should look like this: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/local-cli/templates/HelloWorld/ios/HelloWorld/AppDelegate.m

Comment: Thanks, I did run react-native upgrade, and I can confirm I have the new RCTBundleURLProvider code:
`jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index.ios" fallbackResource:nil];`

Comment: When I try to manually bundle the app via 
`react-native bundle --platform ios --dev false --entry-file index.ios.js --bundle-output iOS/main.jsbundle`

I get this error:

`TransformError: [deleted]/node_modules/firebase/database.js: [deleted]/node_modules/firebase/database.js: Property consequent of ConditionalExpression expected node to be of a type ["Expression"] but instead got null`
Could that be the issue?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Finally resolved my issue. I was using a babel plugin to remove console.log statements as suggested by the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html). Removing the plugin got things working again

Comment: +1 **babel-plugin-transform-remove-console** also broke my RN release builds. 
Sadly **the Facebook guidelines** to remove [Console.log statements](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/performance.html) by using babel-plugin-transform-remove-console do not work. :-(

Comment: **babel-plugin-transform-remove-console doesn't work with RN** https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10412

Answer (score 0):

We solved this by unchecking "Run script only when installing" in XCode->Project Settings->Build Phases->Bundle React Native code and Images

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Facebook is suggesting a **babel-plugin-transform-remove-console** solution that just does not work:
See issue https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/10412

I think something like this is badly needed to auto-remove console.log statements in a release build.